# How to use regular expressions to extract specific substrings and then build into a new string

Tags: java

I need the result String as (Relationship IN (11,12,1) AND (Item=79)).
I have extracted the numbers 11,12 and 1 by the following code:

```
String str = "(( Relationship=11 ) AND ( Relationship=12 ) AND (Item=79) AND ( Relationship=1 ))";
String regex = "Relationship=(\\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) { 
    list.add(matcher.group(1));
    //System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
System.out.println(list.toString());
```

But how do I replace all the `Relationship =` with `Relationship IN ()`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat It's not the same question. It looks like a followup.

Comment: No, here I want to replace the string with a different string

Comment: I want to **replace** - well there is a clue

Comment: The title is almost identical in both questions, which means the title is bad in both (since it doesn't describe the issue).

Comment: @KritiChawla Please fix your title as described in the [ask] page.

Comment: what do you mean `But how do I replace all the Relationship = with Relationship IN ()?` what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This code builds on what you already had, you were very close. It has been tested and as asked it gives you the extracted string " (Relationship IN (11,12,1) AND" in the new String relationshipnumber. There was no need for the List. You can extend the technique in the code to extract the item component of the string.

```
String str = "(( Relationship=11 ) AND ( Relationship=12 ) AND (Item=79) AND ( Relationship=1 ))";
            String regex = "Relationship=(\\d+)";
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);


            String relationshipnumber ="(";
            int i =0;
            while (matcher.find()) { 

                if (i==0){

                    relationshipnumber=relationshipnumber+matcher.group(1);
                }else{

                relationshipnumber=relationshipnumber+","+matcher.group(1);

                }
                i++;
            }
            relationshipnumber="(Relationship IN "+relationshipnumber+ ") AND";
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I replace all the Relationship = with Relationship IN ()?

To do that you can just use [String::replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) like this :

```
String str = "(( Relationship=11 ) AND ( Relationship=12 ) AND "
        + "(Item=79) AND ( Relationship=1 ))";

str = str.replaceAll("Relationship\\s*=", "Relationship IN ()");
System.out.println(str);
```

**Output**

```
(( Relationship IN ()11 ) AND ( Relationship IN ()12 ) AND (Item=79) AND ( Relationship IN ()1 ))
```

---

In case you want to put the inter part between `()` you can use :

```
str = str.replaceAll("Relationship\\s*=\\s*(\\d+)", "Relationship IN ($1)");
```

**Output**

```
(( Relationship IN (11) ) AND ( Relationship IN (12) ) AND (Item=79) AND ( Relationship IN (1) ))
```